# Combining rows in the data set into categories in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to write a script which combines similar entries into the common category.

I have the dataset:

```
product <- c('Laptops','13" Laptops','Apple Laptops', '10 inch laptop','Laptop 13','TV','Big TV')
volume <- c(100,10,20,2,1,200,10)
dataset <- data.frame(product,volume)
```

Looks like:

```
         product volume
1        Laptops    100
2    13" Laptops     10
3  Apple Laptop      20
4 10 inch laptop      2
5      Laptop 13      1
6             TV    200
7         Big TV     10
```

What I want to do is combine all categories together, so for example after running the script I want the dataset to be:

```
         product volume
1        Laptops    113
2  Apple Laptop     20
3  TV               210
```

Since Apple is a brand, I want it to remain separate from categories. I don't know how to get started but I figure I need a for loop to go through every row, and check if a Brand name is in the product name. E.g.

```
brandlist <- 'Apple|Samsung'
if ( grepl(brandlist, dataset$product[i])) { Skip this row }
```

Now I need to **define category names** - which I do by looking at products which most searches, since people tend to search for categories. Let's say a row is a category if the volume is `>100`.

```
categories <- c()
for ( i in 1:count(dataset) ) {
     if ( dataset$volume[i] > 100 ) { categories <- c(categories , dataset$product[i] }}
```

Now I need to check if every row name has a somewhat partial match... I'm thinking of some sort of regex with number + " + category or the other way around. I was also considering some sort of algorithm to check how many letters are different, e.g. allow 4 characters to differ and at least 5 must match exactly to the category, so laptops and 13" laptops will be grouped together since they have 7 characters in common and differ in 4.

**EDIT:**

---

I'm currently thinking along the lines of the following solution:

I made a list of categories, and I created a new data frame such as:

```
category <- c ('other', 'category 1', 'category 2')
volume <- c(0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(category,volume)

    category volume
1 other           0
2 category 1      0
3 category 2      0
```

Now I want to go through results in the previous table using a loop, and match all results (based on the restriction on brands and matching - it must have 1 word in common and could differ in some ways, and put the result in the new data frame.

Comment: Is the identifying product always at the last position? So `... laptop` or are there also `laptop ...` products?

Comment: It could be at the start too, for example in row 5 of dataset. It happens rarely, so I could potentially exclude it. But ideally I'd have some sort of character matching, this way ' xyz laptop abc' will go into 'laptop' as long as there is no brand.

Comment: I'm also considering to do the process manually so look at the dataset, and write code with the condition on non-branding and word containing, get the row data for matching rows, add it to the 2nd 'category' dataset and remove the row from the previous dataset. As rows get deleted, I can manually sort into categories using the method of eliminations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following. First remove all numbers and signes like `"`, `\` or  `" "`. 
Then search for brands and extract the last words, update if there are brands found and print all with lower case. Finally replace the plural `s`. Group and summarize in the last step. Of course this is a hardcoded solution for the provided data.frame, but I see no other way.

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% 
  mutate(p2=gsub("[[:digit:]]|\"","",product),
         p2=stri_trim(p2)) %>% 
  mutate(p3=grepl(brandlist, p2)) %>% 
  mutate(p4=stri_extract_last_words(p2),
         p4=ifelse(p3, grep(brandlist, p2, value=T), p4),
         p4=tolower(p4), 
         p4=stri_replace_last_fixed(p4, "s","")) %>%   
  group_by(p4) %>% 
  summarise(volume=sum(volume)) %>% 
  select(product=p4, volume)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       product volume
         <chr>  <dbl>
1       laptop    113
2           tv    210
3 apple laptop     20
```

Edits:
You can also set up a function. but then you have to create the categories by yourself. Please note to write them in singular and in lower case.

```
library(stringr)
foo <- function(data, product=product, volume=volume, brandlist, categories){
  data %>% 
  mutate(p1=tolower(product)) %>% 
  mutate(p2=str_extract(p1, brandlist),
         p2=ifelse(is.na(p2),"",p2)) %>% 
  mutate(p3=str_extract(p1, categories)) %>% 
  unite(Product, p2, p3, sep = " ") %>%  
  mutate(Product=str_trim(Product)) %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  summarise(volume=sum(volume))
}

foo(dataset, brandlist = 'apple|samsung',categories = "laptop|tv")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
Product volume
<chr>  <dbl>
1 apple laptop     20
2       laptop    113
3           tv    210  

foo(dataset, brandlist = 'apple|samsung',categories = "laptop|tv|big tv")
> foo(dataset, brandlist = 'apple|samsung',categories = "laptop|tv|big tv")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
Product volume
<chr>  <dbl>
1 apple laptop     20
2       big tv     10
3       laptop    113
4           tv    200
```

Comment: I like this solution, but what would happen to a search like 'laptop 13 inch'? It would strip to 'laptop inch'? And create a new category for it. What if I already had the list of categories given and having to allocate current dataset into given categories?

Answer (score 1):

To the first part you can define a categories list and then differentially exclude

```
Categories <- c("Laptop","TV")
Brands <- c("Apple")
Aggregated.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(Categories),function(x){
    SumRow <- sum(dataset[grepl(Categories[x],dataset$product,ignore.case=TRUE),"volume"])
    Excluded <- sapply(1:length(Brands),function(y){
        SumCol <- sum(dataset[grepl(Categories[x],dataset$product,ignore.case=TRUE) & grepl(Brands[y],dataset$product,ignore.case=TRUE),"volume"])
    })
    SumRow  <- ifelse((SumRow - sum(Excluded)) < 0, 0, (SumRow - sum(Excluded)))
    Excluded.df <- NULL
    if(any(Excluded>0)){
        Which <- which(Excluded>0)
        Excluded.df <- data.frame(Product=paste(Brands[Which],Categories[x],sep=" "), volume = Excluded[Which])
    }
    Row.df <- data.frame(Product=Categories[x], volume = SumRow)
    DataFrame <- rbind(Row.df,Excluded.df)
}))
```

> Now I need to define category names - which I do by looking at products which most searches, since people tend to search for categories. Let's say a row is a category if the volume is >100.

```
Min.volume <- 100
Categories <- unique(Aggregated.df$Product[Aggregated.df$volume > Min.volume])
```

Comment: Thanks, this assumes that category name is in the product name. However, some categories are defined as 'laptops' and a lot of products are in single. Would it be possible to do a partial match, for example, similar to the above solution, strip characters, look at the character matching. If >50% characters match -> assign to the category. Else assign to 'other' category as I showed in the edit

Comment: This code is already implementing a near partial match, for example Laptop will already cover Laptop, Laptops, laptop and Laptops. I feel that a partial matching schema would generate too many false positives as it removes contextual meaning from the words. But this is in case you are dealing with very general data. An other category can always be implemented. The best case by me would be to first understand which categories are populating your data.

Comment: I see, the problem with my categories is for example: one of them is called 'new and used cars' but the algorithm won't put 'car old' into such category? Other example would be category 'televisions' when the search name is tvs. Maybe my best bet is to define a list of words and aggregate them into a single category e.g. for each row k in the first dataset, if (grepl('car|cars|vehicle', dataset$product[k]) { df[category='new or old cars'] <- df[category='new or old cars'] $volume + dataset$product[k]